Talend Run subjob if one value is true
I have tFilterRow component that accepts only when today falls into a specific day in my date list, i.e. actual is true. I want to run my subjob if this value is true, else kill the subjob.
My if condition: (input_row.actual.equals("true"))
But it doesn't work.
Can someone please help?
Best,

Is “true” a string or a boolean?

it's a string but I also tried it with boolean with the condition (input_row.actual.equals(true)) and it didn't work either.

Since you mentionned "true" is a string, try this :
"true".equals(input_row.actual)
otherwise if "input_row.actual" contains Null values, your job will throw a NullPointerException
Also check if input_row.actual equals "TRUE" or "True" because equals() is case sensitive
If it still doesnt work add a tJavaRow component and try to log the value with System.out.println("Value of row: " + input_row.actual);
